# Problem with deleting images from database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to delete images from database in Laravel using Postman. I have products and images that are connected through polymorphic relationship. I get error in Postman undefined index images, but when I put that in isset function I no longer get error but just empty screen in postman and it doesn't delete image from database. When I dump validation variable I get empty array. And strange thing happens in my browser when I click on delete button on that image then it erases it in database, but it won't using Postman. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

api.php

```
Route::delete('/products/images/delete', 'ProductController@deleteImage')->name('products.images.delete');
```

ProductController.php

```
public function deleteImage(Request $request)
{
    $validation = request()->validate([
        'image_ids.*' => 'required'
    ], $request->all());
    dd($validation); HERE IT BREAKS AND IT SHOWS EMPTY ARRAY!
    try {
        $this->service->deleteImage($validation['image_ids']);
        return $this->successJson(['success'=> 'Image deleted successfully!'], 200);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return $this->failureJson($exception);
    }
}
```

ProductService.php

```
public function deleteImage($imageIds)
{
    $this->imageService->destroyModelImages($this->product, $imageIds);
}
```

ImageService.php

```
public function destroyModelImages(Model $model, Array $ids)
{
    $pathToFolder = $this->pathToFolderWithImages($model);

    foreach ($ids as $imageId) {
        $image = $model->images->find($imageId);
        Storage::disk($this->disk)->delete($pathToFolder . '/' .  $image->name);
        $image->delete();
    }

    $this->deleteFolderIfIsEmpty($pathToFolder);
}
```

Comment: @KamleshPaul   {{url}}/api/admin/products/images/delete  routes are inside admin group so that works, but for some reason it doesn't delete images

Comment: @KamleshPaul  How would I pass it correctly? It is true, when I dump that it shows empty array

Comment: @KamleshPaul I put in postman body image_ids[] if thats what you mean

Comment: @KamleshPaul  Yes but it is still the same.

Comment: @KamleshPaul It says this error "The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." I added _method and value DELETE in postman body.

Comment: may be it is not able to set body

Comment: @KamleshPaul What exactly do you mean, and how can I test and solve this?

Comment: i think in your case don't use `delete` request use `post` as u need to pass data

Comment: @KamleshPaul Yeah you're right I changed it to post and now I get this error "message": "The given data was invalid.",
        "errors": {
            "image_ids.0": [
                "The image_ids.0 field is required."
            ]

Comment: okay .. to post data use `post`

Comment: @KamleshPaul Okay so I am using post now but I get this error that image_ids field is required. What should I do now?